# Compare table to a list in other worksheet and remove no matches

Tags: excel, vba, compare

I have the following code which compares two lists (Column A in Sheet 1 and Column C in Sheet 2) and deletes the values which are not present in the list of Sheet 2. This code works fine but it does not work when both columns A in Sheet 1 and column C in Sheet 2 has tables. Please let me know how I can modify this code to work for tables as well. Also, how to delete no matches from multiple worksheets having a list in Column C (Sheet 2) constant?

```
Sub Stridhan()

Dim lr As Integer, x As Integer   
lr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False  
For x = lr To 2 Step -1  
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C:C"), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1).Value) = 0 Then  
        Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete  
    End If  
Next x  
Application.ScreenUpdating = True  
End Sub
```

Comment: I might be bit slow today, but what exactly do you mean by "This code works fine but it does not work when both columns A in Sheet 1 and column C in Sheet 2 has tables"? I thought you mean that both columns are part of range formated as table, but when I tried that the code worked ok for me... Also - what does it mean that it doesnt work? It shows error or runs without error, but gives wrong data?

Comment: yes, i meant when the range is formatted as table. The code runs without any errors but does not delete the rows from the table.

Comment: I recreated the file again to make sure and again it works as intended although my data sets are formatted as table. Is there anything else on the Sheet 1? Did you try stepping through the code to see what happens when the delete line is executed?

Comment: I am wondering what might cause this behaviour - if there was anything in sheet 1 that prevented the deletion of line, then it would most probably cause an error. For example if there was a pivot table. So if you see no error I would guess it is more likely that match is not found. Again - stepping through the code to see how it behaves would be the best course of action - does it recognize a match? If no - why? If yes - why doesnt it delete the line? That is how I would proceed.

Comment: Hi, Thanks! its working for me after changing the sheet references. Also, i would want this code to delete no matches from other worksheets as well except first two sheets.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have it run through more sheets you can use code like this

```
Sub cycle_sheets()
For Each sh In Worksheets
    If sh.Name <> "Sheet2" Then
        'your code to cycle through the data where instead of Sheets("SheetX"). you use sh. like this
        sh.Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

this will go through all worksheets and for all that are named differently than "Sheet2" it will perform what is inside the if. So you only need to take your code, change the Sheet reference and put it inside the if.

Edit:
if you want it to skip rows that are not visible due to filtering you can check the row before determining if you want to delete it using

```
If sh.Rows(x).Hidden = False Then
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help on previous query. Now i need to run this code only on filtered rows from column A. However, this code is considering the unfiltered rows and deleting the no matches. I want it to delete no matches only from the filtered rows. Thanks in advance!

Comment: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        Array("Num", "ID", "S"), Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues
        
        lr = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For x = lr To 7 Step -1

            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wn.Range("B:B"), sh.Cells(x, 1).Value) = 0 Then
            sh.Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            Next x
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3